# Google Map/Google Earth Satellite Image of Different Seasons

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

Is there any way where I can get a satellite image from Google Map / Google Earth from different month of the year, or perhaps from different seasons of the year.

Say for example I want to get a satellite image of **New York City on Winter**.

Answer (score 0):

You can view historical imagery in Google Earth via the UI, or by creating [appropriate KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/touring#imagery) or [programmatically](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#time_and_historical_imagery_ui) using the Earth API.